# Bing Maps Directions not working: Shows progress bar forever

Tags: bing-maps, directions

I followed the Bing Maps API for Directions as outlined [here](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#directionsInputPanel+JS) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt736733.aspx). However, in my case the Directions Modules is not working after entering locations (which never seem to be resolved) I get the blue pointed progress bar indefintely:

[image]

I set up a fiddle at http://codepen.io/nachtigall/pen/PzEPEL (scroll down a bit, or open the full page at http://codepen.io/nachtigall/full/PzEPEL/) So it is fully reproducable. The important code is the same as in the documentation:

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function() {
  _this.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(_this.map);
  _this.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: $printoutPanel[0] });
  _this.directionsManager.showInputPanel('directionsInputContainer');
});
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? I can't reproduce it, your code is working perfectly for me, even when I use the exact same end points.

Comment: Yes, I still see it, but it seems like a Cross-Plattform bug. It's not working in Firefox 47 and Firefox 49 (Developer Edition), both on Windows 8.1. It is working in Chrome 51 and IE 11. Firefox' JavaScript Console shows no error.